# Hibernate a user account when switching to different account in Windows 7 Home Premium (64bit)

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate, user-profiles

Is there any way to have Windows 7 hibernate Bob's account when switched to Mary's account and vice versa? I.e.:

1. Bob is logged in
2. Bob clicks *Start >> shutdown >> switch user*
3. Bob's session is saved to disk
4. Mary logs in
5. Mary's session is restored as it was when Bob's turn started

Both are heavy users (30+ chrome tabs open, multiple documents, multiple spreadsheets, music playing, etc) I would like to set up the system so that each gets the full use of the computer while still having all their open apps the way they left them.

I suppose I could try setting up a VM for each, but I'd rather not add anything else to the mix here if I don't have to.

This is Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit running on a Lenovo G550 laptop

Comment: You can of course leave both users signed on at the same time.  The inactive user will occupy some swap space, but probably not enough to hamper the active user.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do, when you close your account the rest of the OS is still working AFAIK, hibernate on the other hand stores everything.

You could do this with two different win7 installs in 2 different disks, thus when you hibernate in one you can boot to the other

Answer (score 2):

No, hibernation is machine-wide and affects all users. However, "switch user" works
just like you desire, and keeps the switching-out user logged in with all his/her
programs open. You can go back and forth between users that way without any of them being
logged out. The switched-out users' programs will still be active and using memory, though,
so your installed memory will have to be large enough to accommodate all the users you
want to have open sessions.